# Cant use an external font

Tags: android, custom-font

I am trying to use an external font, I used someone's answer (can't remember from where), but it crashes on start.

I basically have an assets/fonts folder, in which I put a font.ttf file:
https://i.gyazo.com/2010d3becbabbab35fc8738a6a30689b.png

This is the XML code for the TextView:

```
    <TextView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Text Here."
    android:textSize="30dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="120dp"
    android:textAlignment="center"
    android:id="@+id/howtotv"/>
```

And this is the Java code for it, where I am trying to assign the font:

```
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.howtoplay);
    MyTV = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.howtotv);
    Typeface typeface=Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(), "fonts/archristy.ttf");
    MyTV.setTypeface(typeface);
}
```

The error I'm getting:

Error: Execution failed for task ':app:packageDebug'.

> java.io.FileNotFoundException: D:\AndroidStudioProjects\Tapper2\app\build\intermediates\assets\debug\fonts (access denied)

Comment: check archristy.ttf file in fonts folder

Answer (score 0, accepted):

code seems perfect as per my reference, see link [here](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/android/android_custom_fonts.htm)

try to clean your project once and rebuild it.

Comment: Thank you! Cleaning & Rebuilding the project fixed it.

Comment: happy coding 

Comment: I did, but sadly since I have less than 15 reputation as of now my votes are not publicly displayed, but don't worry, as they are recorded. https://i.gyazo.com/fcfc2ae7312a51caa15b610392578dee.png